# Save Python scripts with .py extension automatically

Tags: python, save, python-idle

In Python IDE, while we save the script, it will prompt the save Dialog. If we specify the filename as "Test". Then file will be saved without extension as "Test" and not "Test.py".

Is it possible to save the script with .py extension automatically (as Test.py)?

Comment: Which python IDE are you using? IDLE?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, IDLE doesn't and can't add the `.py` extension automatically; you will just have to get into the habit of adding it yourself, or use another IDE like Eclipse or Komodo that will do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug report for IDLE about this: http://bugs.python.org/issue10364

If you want, you can edit IDLE itself to do this for you. A good place to start is `save_as` in IOBinding.py.